SWT Browser#setUrl grabs focus
I have 2 views. View1 has a list and View2 contains a Browser widget. Eclipse 2023/09.
When a selection is made in View1, View2 is triggered to show a PDF related to that selection.
So far so good.
If I right-click on the list in View1, a context menu is displayed. However, the right-click also raises a Selection event which causes View2to be updated and the context menu is closed when the Browser#setUrl method is called.
The URL is simply a PDF and no scripts are called. I am pretty sure that the setUrl method causes the Browser to take the focus thereby closing the context menu.
browser = new Browser(parent, 0);
browser.setUrl(url);
browser.update();
parent.layout(true);

If I comment out browser.setUrl(url) the context menu remains open.
I've tried hiding the widget, disabling it, running in asyncExec etc. The result is the same. As soon as setUrl is called, the context menu is closed.
Any ideas how to avoid this behaviour?

It might depend on the HTML of the URL (e.g. by autofocus in HTML or programmatically setting the focus by JavaScript). Have you tried a URL of an almost empty HTML site (e.g. https://example.org/)?

@howlger Good idea. I tried example.org (and a number of other sites) and the problem did not occur with them. I realised that I was using the default browser so I set the SWT.EDGE style which not only does not grab the focus but also displays the PDFs better than the default browser. Thanks.
